# (in Visual Basic) Is it possible to "loop" or "rotate" through a byte, without using an( if-then-tree) or (and &HFF)?

Tags: vb.net, basic

What I mean is: If a byte has value of 255, and I add 1. It becomes 0 again.
Or if I subtract 1 from a zero value it becomes 255.
I have a lot of code, that treats bytes like this,
and I'd rather not sift through all them lines to find occurrences of such *rotations*

Well, nothing ventured and all that...

Cheers
Jhonny

Edit:
Just a dumb example:

```
Sub Tester()
        Dim Arr(255) As Byte
        Dim BytePointer As Byte = 200
        Dim value As Byte
        Arr(50) = 1
        For i = 0 To 5000
            BytePointer = BytePointer + 1
            value = Arr(BytePointer)
            If value = 1 Then MessageBox.Show("Found 1")
        Next
end sub
```

As such it results in an overflow exception.

Can this work without doing:

```
BytePointer = (BytePointer + 1) and &FF
```

Comment: you have not explained what you are trying to achieve, you have a lot of code that does unsigned overflow, go that, but what do you want to outcome to be. You want to stop bytes from wrapping without changing the code? Do you want to detect which ones are overflowing?

Comment: For instance: a byte keeps track of a position in an array of 256 items. Just by adding 1 to it it will iterate through the whole array, no matter what the starting-position was.

Comment: are you saying you want to make basic code that does that wrapping around

Comment: Yes, I guess. I added an example. to illustrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK....

By "Removing integer overflow checks in the Advanced Compiler Options dialog", you can wrap-around bytes and integers, without overflow-errors.

But it does so for the whole project.

I can work with this...

It's a shame though, that VB does not offer variables (let's call them winteger or wbyte) that do this by default. (just my 2 cents...)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the BASIC that you use, but this answer assumes FreeBasic.

### You should declare the *BytePointer* variable as `UByte`.

The number range for `Byte` is from -128 to +127 ("signed"), but for `UByte` it is 0 to 255 ("unsigned") which nicely matches the array bounds.

When your code initializes the *BytePointer* variable with `Dim BytePointer As Byte = 200`, FreeBasic already sets it at -56, and when your code increments the *BytePointer* variable with `BytePointer = BytePointer + 1` it becomes -55.
The instruction `value = Arr(BytePointer)` will not address an element of your array since this index (-55) is out of bounds (0,255).

Next code works fine and has no problem with the wraparound from 255 back to 0:

```
Dim Arr(255) As Byte
Dim BytePointer As UByte = 251
Dim value As Byte
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 255
  Arr(i)=i
Next
For i = 1 To 10
  value = Arr(BytePointer)
  Print BytePointer, value
  BytePointer = BytePointer + 1
Next
```

Comment: That would be exactly what I want.

Comment: Except I want to use the code in Visual Basic ( did not put the wright tag with this question ) As far as I can tell; UByte is not part of the program? But thanks a lot Sep, for the answer. FreeBasic is probably the only Basic I have not tried in my life...

Comment: Why assume Free Basic when the OP specified VB.NET?

Comment: @Enigmativity The VB.NET tag was added *after* the answer was posted. Also, most modern day BASICs aren't that different, I hope...

Comment: The OP (me) did put the tag on after Sep had already answered. sorry for the mishap! BASICs  ARE different, mainly in the small details. Such as, that VB.net has no Ubyte...

Comment: @JhonnyQ Does VB.net allow you to define an array between bounds like in `Dim Arr(+128 To 127) As Byte`? If it does, then the signed wraparound on the signed *BytePointer* variable would normally not matter.

Comment: @SepRoland - Sorry, I should have checked the history.

Comment: @SepRoland: Yes,I know enough workarounds like that. the problem I have: is that in my source-codes, all byte-variables wrap-around ( in that BASIC-version) and they are hard to spot...and easy to miss...